# ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED for workbox source maps when PWA is accessed offline

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have a workbox service worker which is supposed to add certain urls to a cache and update the cache using StaleWhileRevalidate and use background sync for offline post requests. This is the service worker

```js
importScripts("/third_party/workbox/workbox-v6.5.3/workbox-sw.js");

workbox.setConfig({
  debug: true,
  modulePathPrefix: "/third_party/workbox/workbox-v6.5.3/",
});

const { registerRoute, Router } = workbox.routing;
const { StaleWhileRevalidate } = workbox.strategies;
const { CacheableResponsePlugin } = workbox.cacheableResponse;
const { RangeRequestsPlugin } = workbox.rangeRequests;

const router = new Router();

const urls = [/*URLs to be cached including all files in the workbox folder*/];

const exclude = ({ url, request, event }) => {
  let exclude =
    url.pathname.match(/tools\/horario/) ||
    url.pathname.match(/tools\/modal_abierto/);
  let include = !exclude;
  return include;
};

self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
  const strategy = new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: "demo-cache",
    plugins: [
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({
        statuses: [0, 200],
      }),
      new RangeRequestsPlugin(),
    ],
  });

  registerRoute(exclude, strategy);

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open("demo-cache").then(function (cache) {
      return cache.addAll(urls);
    })
  );

  const { Queue } = workbox.backgroundSync;

  const queue = new Queue("myQueueName");

  POSThandler = ({ url, request, event, params }) => {
    const bgSyncLogic = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(event.request.clone());
        return response;
      } catch (error) {
        await queue.pushRequest({ request: event.request });
        return error;
      }
    };
    event.respondWith(bgSyncLogic());
  };
  POSTinclude = () => {
    return true;
  };
  registerRoute(POSTinclude, POSThandler, "POST");
  
  workbox.routing.setDefaultHandler(strategy);
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  const { request } = event;
  const responsePromise = router.handleRequest({
    event,
    request,
  });
  if (responsePromise) {
    // Router found a route to handle the request.
    event.respondWith(responsePromise);
  } else {
    // No route was found to handle the request.
  }
});
```

This works and serves the whole page on reloads using devtools offline but when actually the device goes offline it shows the chrome dino page and these are the

[image: contents of the console.]

Is there something I am missing? How can this be fixed?